# Need to printf script's arguments

Tags: bash

I'm trying to list script's argument by `printf` function. Arguments are counted by iteration of `$i`. What should be in `printf` function?
I need something like

```
eval echo \$$i
```

but in `printf` function.

Edit: Have while cycle with iteration of `$i` and among other code, I have

```
printf "%s" $i
```

But, instead of `$i`, I need some code, that shows me value of argument.
In my case, it is name of file, and I need list them. One file in one iteration.

Comment: Normally, you do that with `i=1;for arg in "$@"; do echo "$i: $arg"; ((i++)); done`, iterating through the list of arguments.  Is there any reason why you can't do that too?

Comment: I cant use echo, because I'm formating the text, this is not whole printf I use, but only problem I have

Comment: OK; don't use `echo`; use: `i=1;for arg in "$@"; do printf "%s\n" "$i: $arg"; ((i++)); done`.  That produces the same thing as the `echo` does.  You can vary the formatting to suit yourself.  See also my answer.  It would also help if you showed enough context for what you want to do and what you have tried that we can see how to help you properly, rather than having to guess what it is you want us to help you with.

Comment: If you want to render nonprintable characters in such a way as to make them readable, you might consider `printf '%q'`. Be aware that this is a bashism, unavailable in POSIX printf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in a comment, you normally do that with a loop such as:

```
i=1
for arg in "$@"
do
    echo "$i: [$arg]"
    ((i++))
done
```

(If `echo` isn't allowed, use `printf "%s\n" …` where the `…` is whatever would have followed `echo`.)

You might also use indirect expansion to avoid the use of `eval`:

```
for i in 1 2 3 4; do echo "$i: [${!i}]"; done
```

You can generalize that with:

```
for i in $(seq 1 $#); do echo "$i: [${!i}]"; done
```

or

```
for ((i = 1; i <= $#; i++)); do echo "$i: [${!i}]"; done
```

For example, given:

```
set -- a b 'c  d' '  e  f  '
```

all the loops produce the output:

```
1: [a]
2: [b]
3: [c  d]
4: [  e  f  ]
```

The square brackets are merely there to delimit the argument values; it allows you to see the trailing blanks on the fourth line of output.

You might also be able to use:

```
printf "[%s]\n" "$@"
```

to get:

```
[a]
[b]
[c  d]
[  e  f  ]
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps me, epsecially the part with "$i: [${!i}]". Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

It is not very clear what you are asking for, but this will list the arguments passed to the script:

```
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
    printf "%s\n" "$1"
    shift
done
```

Comment: You could write: `printf "%s\n" "$@"` and get the same result.

Comment: Aha, definitely nicer!

Comment: Sorry, I edited my main post. English is not my native language, so I hope it is a clearer for you

Comment: Well if I get your edit correctly, the while loop with the `shift` should do what you want.

Comment: Right, added the qoutes.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are asking for is how to make the indirect reference to positional parameter `i` (i containing the position):

```
print "%s\n" ${!i}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is it, similar answer contain answer by Jonathan.

Comment: This is buggy -- an argument with `"hello world"` would render as two lines, one with `hello` and the other with `world`.

Answer (score 0):

To get your arguments in such a way that they can be fed back into the shell with the exact same value, the following bash extension can be used:

```
printf '%q ' "$@"; printf '\n'
```

This works even for rather unusual cases. Let's say that one of your arguments contains a newline:

```
./your-script 'hello
world' 'goodbye world'
```

This will be represented in the printf output:

```
$'hello\nworld' goodbye\ world
```

...with something you can use again in the shell:

```
$ echo $'hello\nworld' goodbye\ world
hello
world goodbye world
```